# FB api not asking for manage_pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, api

When logging in as the user that created the app, the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions are asked for and granted. When logging in as another user, the manage_pages permission is not asked for and not granted however publish_stream is. The code is below:

```
jQuery.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: ''
    });

    FB.login(function(response) {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
              FB.api('/' + pageid + '/feed', 'post', 
              { 
                access_token: "",
                message     : "hello",
                to: pageid,
                from: pageid,
              }, 
              function(response) {
                //response
              });
            }
        }); 
    }, {scope: 'manage_pages,publish_stream', return_scopes: true});
});
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Is the permission approved by Facebook (new apps permission(s) review)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit a request for the 'manage_pages' permission to be granted to your app. Only then can you ask for that permission from other users besides the admin/developer of your app. Check the link below for more info:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Answer (score 0):

You must ask facebook to allow your App to request this permission.

Here are the instructions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages